# Create a Column Based on Another Column Using grepl

Tags: r, string, dataframe, grepl, startswith

Let's consider a `df` with two columns `word` and `stem`. I want to create a new column that checks whether the value in `stem` is entailed in `word` and whether it is preceded or succeeded by some more characters. The final result should look like this:

```
WORD     STEM     NEW
rerun    run      prefixed
runner   run      suffixed
run      run      none
...      ...      ...
```

And below you can see my code so far. However, it does not work because the `grepl` expression is applied on all rows of the `df`. Anyways, I think it should make clear my idea.

```
df$new <- ifelse(grepl(paste0('.+', df$stem, '.+'), df$word), 'both',
             ifelse(grepl(paste0(df$stem, '.+'), df$word), 'suffixed',
                ifelse(grepl(paste0('.+', df$stem), df$word), 'prefixed','none')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `new` column like this

```
df$new <- ifelse(startsWith(df$word, df$stem) & endsWith(df$word, df$stem), 'none',
                 ifelse(startsWith(df$word, df$stem), 'suffixed',
                        ifelse(endsWith(df$word, df$stem), 'prefixed',
                               'both')))
```

Or, in you are in a `dplyr` pipeline and you want to avoid all the annoying `df$`

```
df %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(startsWith(df$word, df$stem) & endsWith(df$word, df$stem), 'none',
                      ifelse(startsWith(df$word, df$stem), 'suffixed',
                             ifelse(endsWith(df$word, df$stem), 'prefixed',
                                    'both'))))
```

Output

```
#       word stem     new1
# 1    rerun  run prefixed
# 2   runner  run suffixed
# 3      run  run     none
# 4    aruna  run     both
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I select this answer as the solution because is it the most similar compared to my approach. Anyways, the Ian Campbell also solves the problem

Comment: @hyhno01 Just to let you know, I've updated my answer: I canceled the part in which I compare the `nchar` of word and stem because I realised that it was superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mapply` to use `grepl` per line like:

```
ifelse(mapply(grepl, paste0(".+", x$STEM, ".+"), x$WORD), "both",
ifelse(mapply(grepl, paste0(x$STEM, ".+"), x$WORD), "suffixed",
ifelse(mapply(grepl, paste0(".+", x$STEM), x$WORD), "prefixed", "none")))
#"prefixed" "suffixed"     "none"
```

Or using `startsWith` and `endsWith` and use subseting form vector:

```
c("none", "both", "prefixed", "suffixed")[1 + (1 + startsWith(x$WORD, x$STEM) +
 2*endsWith(x$WORD, x$STEM)) * (nchar(x$WORD) > nchar(x$STEM) &
 mapply(grepl, x$STEM, x$WORD))]
#[1] "suffixed" "prefixed" "none"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `str_locate` from `stringr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(WORD,STEM), as.character) %>%
  mutate(NEW = 
         case_when(str_locate(WORD,STEM)[,"start"] > 1 &
                   str_locate(WORD,STEM)[,"end"] < nchar(WORD) ~ "both",
                   str_locate(WORD,STEM)[,"start"] > 1 ~ "prefixed",
                   str_locate(WORD,STEM)[,"end"] < nchar(WORD) ~ "suffixed",
                   TRUE ~ "none"))
    WORD STEM      NEW
1  rerun  run prefixed
2 runner  run suffixed
3    run  run     none
```

I added a line to convert `WORD` and `STEM` to character in case they were factors.